# How to give a parameter from the Main to an agent in Anylogic

Tags: java, parameters, radio-button, agent, anylogic

my Main contains a conveyor, which transports a carton (my agent) from A to B. I added a radio button with which the user can choose the size of the box ("small", "medium", "big" & "very big"). I now want every carton to save the value of the radio button. I tried a lot of different stuff like linking it to a parameter, but I didn't manage to figure it out.

Picture of my model:

[image]

the code I used for the radio button is:

```
if( value == 0 )
    radioValue = 1;
else if( value == 1 )
    radioValue = 2;
else if( value == 2 )
    radioValue = 3;
 else if( value == 3 )
    radioValue = 4;
```

radioValue being the parameter in the Main i linked my radio-button to.

How do I give this parameter to the agent and how do I read it out later?

Thanks in advance for helping!

Comment: Could be nice if you could provide us your code so we can have a better idea of what you already tried

Comment: Hi Corentin, thanks for the reply. I edited the post, but I didn't use much code yet.

Comment: Unfortunatly, this sample doens't help that much get where you're doing wrong

Comment: more information is needed on your model

Comment: ok maybe I should rephrase a little bit. I'm trying to give my agent the value from the code above. So if the user selected "small" as a radio-button option the value is 0 and the parameter "radioValue" is 1 for this specific carton. My aim is that the carton remembers that it is small, but don't know how to do it.

Comment: to do that you need to create a variable in your agent and you have to do agent.variable=radioValue ... but the details on this depend on wether you are using discrete events or agent based, it depends on wether it's only 1 agent or a population of agents... etc

Comment: Hi Felipe, thanks for your answer. Im pretty new to Anylogic so it's kind of hard for me to answer these questions, but I added a screenshot of my model above, so maybe that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your Kist agent create a variable called size of type int.

in the source block, in the properties, on the "on at exit" action, under the action section of the properties write the following code:

```
agent.size=radioValue;
```

This is one of the most basic things to do in AnyLogic... so I suggest for you to go through a training before even starting to work on any model. This can be done by going through the tutorials, the anylogic in 3 days book or my course here: [noorjax.teachable.com/p/anylogic](https://noorjax.teachable.com/p/anylogic)

later you can use agent.size to access the size of your agent, in any of the blocks.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing more of the code, my general suggestion would be to consider looping through the agents (e.g., with a for loop) and having them all set a local variable cartSize equal to radioValue (I wouldn't use "size" because its also used for agentsets I believe). Just spitballing here, but something like this?

```
for (int x = 0; x < carton.size(); x++) {
     carton.get(x).cartSize = radioValue;
}
```

Comment: this only works if you have a custom population for your PML model and it changes the size for all the population instead of just for the ones arriving, which is not what you would want... and using size is fine for a variable name :)

Comment: Ah, I assumed there was a custom population there. I like the solution you've given below, more elegant assuming it works for the poster. 
And while using size is fine, it should be discouraged by convention. Using something else will help keep things more easy, at least cognitively in development.

Comment: can you point out where it is stated that size is a variable name that shouldn't be used by convention? I don't see why it wouldn't be used...

Comment: while "size" is not a "reserved word" in java (so it wouldn't be a technical violation of any official conventions, it is used a lot in AnyLogic a lot (and java generally) for collections, so using it can cause confusion and make the code less interpretable. 
You're welcome to do it, but myself and others who teach M&S and publish AnyLogic models suggest against it. Having size function in two ways in the same model just introduces a point of potential confusion that could easily be avoided.